# Mysqli Undefined index array json

Tags: php, mysqli

i have notice with sum metode : "Undefined index: PGW maximum active subscribers "

```js
$a=mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT sum(`PGW maximum active subscribers`) as count FROM ggsn_4g_pdp_max");
 $b=mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT sum('SGW maximum active subscribers') as count FROM ggsn_4g_pdp_max");
 $c=mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT sum('SPGW maximum active subscribers') as count FROM ggsn_4g_pdp_max");
 
 
    $pgw_array=array();
    $sgw_array=array();
    $spgw_array=array();
    
 
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($a)){
        $pgw_array[]= $r["PGW maximum active subscribers"];
 }
 while($g=mysqli_fetch_array($b)){
        $sgw_array[]= $g["SGW maximum active subscribers"];
 }
  while($n=mysqli_fetch_array($c)){
        $spgw_array[]= $n["SPGW maximum active subscribers"];
 }
```

how i can fixed...?please

Comment: `var_dump($r);` will shows you what this variable actually contains.

Comment: You're selecting the field *`as count`*, so that's what it's called in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the alias `count`: `$r["count"]`